# Relation between k and k-1 edge connected graph

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, graph-connectivity

Is every k connected graph is k-1 connected or the reverse? I always get confused. Can someone explain with the help of an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that it depends on your definition, and if you provide the definition you are using I can be more specific.

1. The definition on [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-ConnectedGraph.html) is that a graph is $k$-connected if
       for every set of $k-1$ vertices, removing those vertices doesn't
       disconnect it. In this case, if a graph is $k$-connected then it is
       also $\ell$-connected for all $\ell<k$. To see this, notice that if
       removing many vertices cannot disconnect the graph, then you have no
       hope of disconnecting the graph by removing fewer vertices.
2. The definition on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph) is that a graph is $k$-connected if
           $k$ is the smallest positive integer such that deleting $k$ vertices
           can disconnect the graph. Because of the use of the word "smallest,"
           a $k$-connected graph is neither $(k-1)$-connected nor
           $(k+1)$-connected. Under this definition, a clique on $m$ vertices is considered to be $(m-1)$-connected
3. Another definition I have seen is that a graph is $k$-connected if
           there is a set of $k$ vertices such that removing them disconnects
           the graph. Under this definition, a graph that is
           $k$-connected is also $\ell$-connected for all $\ell > k$ since we
           can choose the $\ell$ vertices by first picking the $k$ vertices
           known to disconnect the graph, and then picking the remaining
           $\ell-k$ vertices arbitrarily.

Definition $1$ and $3$ come at the problem from "different sides" in some sense, and definition $2$ is equivalent to requiring that both definition $1$ and $3$ hold.

Comment: Never a bad idea to have more alternatives for things that are not agreed upon conventionally. Note that I still don't know whether a graph with $k$ vertices (possibly with no edges for definition 2) would be considered $k$-connected automatically. One would have to look that up. Possibly one should define $0$-connected to be regular connectedness, and then $k$-connected requires $k-1$-connectedness as well as the ability to remove $k-1$ vertices without disconnecting the graph.

Comment: @Arthur Wikipedia clarifies that $K_m$ is $(m-1)$ connected, which handles the only issue there. I've included that detail in my answer now.

Comment: And if i'm wrong it's same for edge connectivity! I mostly stick to first definition and due to other definitions i always get myself confused. Thanks for making it explicit.